# creating pdf in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

**Hi, I am following a tutorial on flutter about pdf creation.
I followed all of the steps and on the tutorial video it is working but on my end it doesn't. I'm just lost on why it is not working on my end. I followed every detail on the video that I am watching. Kindly Explain to me what i have done wrong, and if can, if possible a fix to the error**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:ppmobile/installers/pdf/PDfPreview.dart';

class MyAppforPDf extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PdfTest(),
    );
  }
}

class PdfTest extends StatelessWidget {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  writeOnPdf() {
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(32),
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Header(
              level: 0,
              child: pw.Text("1st header"),
            ),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Header(level: 1, child: pw.Text("2nd ehader")),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
            pw.Paragraph(text: "TEST PDF"),
          ];
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future savePdf() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
    File file = File("$documentPath/example.pdf");
    file.writeAsBytesSync(pdf.save()); <------------------------------- this is the one that has problem
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "PDF TUTORIAL",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          writeOnPdf();
          await savePdf();

          Directory documentDirectory =
              await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
          String fullPath = "$documentPath/example.pdf";

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => PdfPreviewScreen(
                path: fullPath,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.save),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest i dont know why. but adding await on "file.writeAsBytesSync(pdf.save());" fixed it.

so..

from `"file.writeAsBytesSync(pdf.save());"` to `"file.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());"`

fixed it for me.

Thank you osama asif from the other Q&A threads out there in the internet for the answer.